# How to get application.js which doesn't include compressed code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run Rails server, I want to use `application.js` which doesn't include compressed JavaScript code.

In my environment, a compressed one already exists in public/assets/application.js. Though I added a code as follows to `development.rb`, I still get `application.js` with compressed code.

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

Can I get it without executing rake assets:clean or deleting public/assets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `rake assets:clobber` or `rake assets:clean` should help.

```
rake assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
```

You probably ran assets:precompile which compiles the assets and places them at the public folder. And rails will serve any files that are present there. So cleaning it should solve your problem.